# How to use dynamic file name in Log4j.xml?

Tags: log4j

how to read property from properties file and use in log4j.xml if not found then use default path.

For an instance

```
<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">    
    <param name="File" value="logs/${logfilename}.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d::[%t]::%-5p::%c::%x - %m%n" />
    </layout>       
</appender>
```

In above code snippet, I want to retrieve value of logfilename from properties file.If I mentioned `logfilename=abc_log` in property file then `abc_log.log` should be generated inside logs folder. If I am unable to find logfilename properties then by default location should be called for an instance `/logs/default.log`

could you please help in this, How I can achieve the above approach?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a code for using Log4J for dynamically generate filename. It changes its name according to input file name and current date-time. (So helpful in case you run same file multiple times.) (Found this in another thread)

```
public class LogClass {

private static Logger log =  Logger.getLogger(LogClass.class);
private static boolean initializationFlag = false;
private static String fileName;

private static void intializeLogger(){
    log.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();

    RollingFileAppender appender = new RollingFileAppender();
    appender.setAppend(true);
    appender.setMaxFileSize("1MB");
    appender.setMaxBackupIndex(1);
    appender.setFile(fileName + "_" + dateFormat.format(date) + ".log");

    PatternLayout layOut = new PatternLayout();
    layOut.setConversionPattern("%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n");
    appender.setLayout(layOut);

    log.addAppender(appender);
}

public static Logger getLogger(){
    if(initializationFlag == false){
        intializeLogger();
        initializationFlag = true;
        return LogClass.log;
    }
    else{
        return LogClass.log;
    }
}

public static void setFileName(String fileName){
    LogClass.fileName = fileName;
}
```